Last element position move to right in carousel
I created a carousel view to display shopping cards but last card having showing more white space to right side.
SnapCarousel I am using.
How can I set padding or trailing?
How can I set card position more to right side?
SnapCarouselView(
    itemsPadding: Spacing._12,
    trailingSpaces: Spacing._20 * 5,
    index: $viewModel.selectedIndex,
    list: viewModel.cartProducts,
    showIndicator: true,
    contentView: {
        cartProduct in CardView(viewModel: CartViewModel(cartId: cartProduct.Id, name: cartProduct.name, description: cartProduct.description, subTitle: cartProduct.subTitle))
    }
)




https://developer.apple.com/wwdc23/10159
